# Why am I getting a WA in Faded Palindromes in Codechef even though I found no error till now in my code and its working fine for me?

Tags: c++

I have been debugging and seeing this code for nearly a week now still I couldn't find any solution and thus hoping to get one from the fellow developers in stack overflow.

This is the solution of the Faded Palindrome problem of September Challenge Codechef [This is the problem page](https://www.codechef.com/SEPT16)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<cstdio>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
string def="-1";
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    //vector<string> out(t);
    string out[100];
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        string inp;
        cin>>inp;
        if(inp.size()%2)   //Checking wether the number of letters is odd
        {
            int counter=inp.size()/2;
            int counter_back=counter-1;
            int counter_front=counter+1;
            if(inp[counter]=='.')
            inp[counter]='a';
            int not_fa=0;
            while(counter_back>=0&&counter_front<inp.size())
            {
                if(inp[counter_back]==inp[counter_front])
                  {counter_back--;counter_front++;}
                else if(inp[counter_back]=='.'&&inp[counter_front=='.']){
                inp[counter_back]=inp[counter_front]='a';
                counter_back--;counter_front++;
                }
                else if(inp[counter_back]=='.'){
                inp[counter_back]=inp[counter_front];
                counter_back--;counter_front++;
                }
                else if(inp[counter_front]=='.'){
                inp[counter_front]=inp[counter_back];
                counter_back--;counter_front++;
                }
                else{
                    not_fa=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(not_fa)
               out[i]=def;
            else
                out[i]=inp;
        }
        else{      //Checking the number of letter is even
            //cout<<inp.size();
            int counter_front=(inp.size())/2;
            //cout<<counter_front;
            int counter_back=counter_front-1;
            //cout<<counter_back;
            int not_fa=0;
            while(counter_back>=0&&counter_front<inp.size())
            {
                if(inp[counter_back]==inp[counter_front])
                  {//cout<<"*-";
                  counter_back--;counter_front++;}
                else if(inp[counter_back]=='.'&&inp[counter_front]=='.'){
                inp[counter_back]=inp[counter_front]='a';
                counter_back--;counter_front++;
                }
                else if(inp[counter_back]=='.'){
                //cout<<"--";
                inp[counter_back]=inp[counter_front];
                counter_back--;counter_front++;
                }
                else if(inp[counter_front]=='.'){
                inp[counter_front]=inp[counter_back];
                counter_back--;counter_front++;
                }
                else{
                    not_fa=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(not_fa)
                out[i]=def;
            else
                out[i]=inp;

        }
    }
    /*vector<string>::iterator itr;
    for(itr=out.begin();itr!=out.end();itr++)
        cout<<*itr<<endl;*/
    for(int j=0;j<t;j++)
    if(j==t-1)
        cout<<out[j];
    else
        cout<<out[j]<<"\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your code may pass all the test cases presented in the problem statement, there are still more edge cases that your code doesn't cover. Here's a sample test case:

```
6
..
...
..e
a..a.v.
p..p
t.xzt
```

This should print:

```
aa
aaa
eae
avaaava
paap
tzxzt
```

instead it prints:

```
..
.a.
aaa
aa.a.aa
p..p
taxat
```

Hints:

1. The first if statement is not correctly handling the case where `inp[b]` and `inp[f]` are both `'.'`.
2. There is no need for doing two different things when |s| is even or odd.
3. Also, in the first `else if` statement, you probably meant `inp[counter_front]=='.'` instead of `inp[counter_front=='.']`.

Answer (score 0):

`if(inp[counter_back]==inp[counter_front])` is true if they both are equal to `'.'` so you won't fill that gap.